# How to hide a grouping field in tableau which breaks down the subtotal but should not be displayed in the report?

Tags: tableau-api

I am new user of tableau and working on a specific reporting requirement where I have to display subtotal by field 1, field 2 & field 3 but should not display field 1 in the report.
Is there any direct way to hide the field from the view which still contributes to the grand total?

Comment: Is each "field" a column in your data or is each "field" some of the values in the set of a single column?

Comment: Right click the field, click hide

Answer (score 0):

Right click on the field and uncheck the show header option